# How to match and exclude "!x" with regex?

Tags: java, regex, skip

I have been trying to come up with a regex for Java to match a bot command:

```
!x play search words here
```

where the x can be any alphanumeric character and it works with:

```
"(?:\\w)(\\w+)"
```

However if I want to use alias "p" for "play", the regex will skip the "p" also. I've been also trying to get the skip match to work with exclamation mark without success.

One workaround I found was to use:

```
"[^\\!\\w]+(\\w+)"
```

but then the first match is " p" with whitespace. I just can't figure this out!

Comment: Try `"(?<!!)\\b\\w+"`

Comment: Thanks so much, it works! Care to explain how it works?

Comment: Care to read [the docs of Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?  Or at least to ask a more specific question?

Comment: I was putting children to bed, sorry. They behave as if it were Friday today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid matching words preceded with `!`, you may use

```
"\\b(?<!!)\\w+"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lShfBS/2)

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!!)` - a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  making sure there cannot be `!` right before the current position
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

Note that lookbehinds are zero-width assertions, they just signal the regex engine whether to go on matching or stop (the text matched does not get added to the current matched text).